# How do I paint over a textured ceiling without removing the texture?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, texture

A painter I had at one time painted the textured drywall mud ceiling (off white color) in a different part of the house.  He had to change to a sprayer because he said the drywall texture was coming off with the roller.  I want to paint the same type of ceiling for a small bathroom.  I don't have a sprayer.  I am afraid to paint due to the texture coming off.  It has never been painted over this texture before.  Do you think I can wet it and scrape it off and still do a light sanding to get a smooth finish?  Or forget everything including the paint and leave like it is?  I am not sure what is under this texture and whether it will be ready to paint and have a smooth finish?

Comment: for the painting part, see : http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/1167/86

Comment: for the removal part, see : http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/431/86

Answer (score 1):

**Priming then painting:** The texture is water based, so you need to prime first with oil or shellac based primer.  This will seal the texture and "waterproof" it.

Use plenty of ventilation and possibly an organic respirator.

Once primed, any paint can be used (make sure the full drying interval is used).

**Removing**: will work before any painting.  Put down waterproof tarp, wall-to-wall and taped 6" up.  Use a misting  hand sprayer or a garden sprayer.  Let soak 15 min, respraying  if dry spots develop.  Scrape with a long handled pole and a stiff angled putty knife.  Keep the knife flat and start slowly until you get a rhythm.  No sense in making another repair for gouges.  Clean any residue with a new sponge mop and some TSP or a light detergent.