# Tips To Inspect/ Popcorn ceilings

Tags: ceiling, popcorn, asbestos

My wife and I are considering buying a house that was built in the 1960s and has acoustic "popcorn" ceilings.  I want to know if there is a cheap, effective way to do a home asbestos test.

I'm still reviewing some of the inspection reports but I don't think they've specifically checked for this.

Tips, anyone?

-M

Comment: Just a follow-up comment/recommendation to other home owners: collect more than one sample.  My initial asbestos test came back negative but that was because it was very small.  I'm really glad I tested again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get this [test kit](http://www.acehardware.com/product/index.jsp?productId=1296032&CAWELAID=109329982) for about $10. You have to cut out/scrape off a sample to send to a lab. (Make sure you wet the area first to avoid any airborne particles.) You also have to include another $30 with the sample for standard analysis.

Instructions [here](http://www.prolabinc.com/instructions/asbestos.html).

Answer (score 7):

For future reference- there is no need to buy these kits.  They are essentially selling you a zip-top baggie for $10.00.

Simply wet the area, and scrape a very small sample into a zip-top bag of your own.  Then place this bag into another sealable bag (i.e.- double-bag the sample).  Then you can call one of several national testing labs, that will perform the test for around $10-15/sample, and email you the results. Google asbestos testing labs.  Some labs will only test for professionals, but many will take home-owner samples- you just have to call around a bit.

Comment: Thanks Mark -- Yea, I realized this after I opened the kit and saw the somewhat dismal contents.